# How do I make Firefox 7 remember my history shorter/longer?

Tags: firefox, history

I want to setup Firefox 7 to store my history for longer or shorter (setting period of time, just like in Options), but I can't seem to find an option to do that in dialog; all I can see is "Remember History".

Answer (score 2):

Use [Expire history by days](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/expire-history-by-days/?src=search). It's a Firefox extension.

Comment: This seems to be able to shorten the time to expiration by deleting older history, but how do I extend the expiration time?

Answer (score 0):

Since version 4, Firefox does not limit the history by the number of days.

Firefox now uses heuristics to determine the number of entries stored in history. In essence, Firefox will store as many entries as it determines it can without reducing performance.

For more information, see:

- http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/856021
- http://blog.bonardo.net/2010/01/20/places-got-async-expiration.